# Spring MVC | requestDispatcher & sendRedirect

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there a framework provided/specific way where we can do requestDispatcher and sendRedirect similar to simple Java EE MVC applications?

Please suggest the methods.

Answer (score 4):

you can redirect in spring like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(ModelMap model) {            
        // process form data

        model.addAttribute("notification", "Successfully did it!");
        return "redirect:/form";
    }
```